# water doesn't flow inside closed sphere

Tags: fluid-simulation, collision

I checked many tutorials and guides on how domain and the liquid engine works.
I also troubleshooted all the common problems why water does not flow and after hours of researching I found a fix myself that doesn't really make sense to me.

When I add a sphere and add the liquid quick effect set to geometry, then add another (outer) sphere with a subdivision applied, scaled up, inverted the normals and added a liquid effector type collision then the water will not flow once baked.

Now when I cut a hole inside the outer sphere, then the water will flow. See the picture below.
[image]

Now every tutorial and guide I've seen out there does not apply this method by cutting a hole inside of the outer collision sphere.

I'm wondering why I'm required to do this in order for it to work. Am I missing something?
Any advice would be helpful!

Comment: Be sure to search this forum for "liquid flow" (no quotes) and you'll see many postings that might help.  Subtleties like Effector Collision Thickness must be > 0.5 are discussed that could help you solve your problem..  Else you can post your blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ . (copy/paste the HTML provided into your question above (Edit).

Comment: other people are happy if they know a solution which works, and you wanna know why ;) well...that is ambitious! ;)